# How to use powershell to remove and replace a character

Tags: powershell, csv, replace

I am trying to remove a "-" Dash from a column of imported data. I just do not know how to do it, any help would be appreciated.

The process I am doing is importing Data from an existing CSV file making some changes and exporting it to another CSV file to be imported into an application. The application now no longer supports the "-" Dash so I need to replace it with a space.

Existing data
0001-00001,LastName, FirstName Initial.

My Powershell Script

```
#Import Perfect Law File "clntsimp.imp" File inserting Headers inot the existing data
Import-Csv clntsimp.imp -Header Name,LastName,FirstName |

#Piped above information and remove the "-" from the "Name" column and add a "Blank Space"
$Content = Get-Content $_."
ForEach-Object { $Content -replace "-", " "}} |

#Piped above information and combine the "LastName" and "FirstName" Fields inot a single field named "Description" seperated by a "," and "Blank Space"
Select-Object *,@{Name='Description';Expression={$_.Lastname,$_.FirstName -join ', '}} |

#piped above information adding a third column header "Status" and fill in the rows with "Active"
Select-Object Name,Description,@{Name='Status';Expression={'Active'}} |

#Piped above information and export to a new file named "Sendpro.cvs" 
Export-Csv sendpro1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The result I am looking for is

"Name","Description","Status"
"0001 00001","LastName, FirstName Initial.","Active"

Aside from this new section below, it all works as expected, I just can't figure out how to replace the "-" Dash with a space to accommodate the change I need to make

```
#Piped above information and remove the "-" from the "Name" column and add a "Blank Space"
$Content = Get-Content $_.Name"
ForEach-Object { $Content -replace "-", " "}} |
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am still learning Powershell. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to change just the header, or all the data as well?

Answer (score 0):

In your example of `-Replace '-',' '` should've been all that's needed. There're quite a few syntax issues but I am assuming it's due to you sanitizing the code. With that said, you can use a `pscustomobject` to re-order the structure of the properties.

```
Import-Csv .\clntsimp.imp -Header Name, LastName, FirstName | ForEach-Object -Process {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name        = $_.Name -replace '\p{Pd}',' '
            Description = $_.LastName, $_.FirstName -join ', '
            Status      = 'Active'
        }
    } #| Export-Csv -Path .\sendpro1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This allows for some code alteration by assigning the properties to the `pscustomobject`. Now, all that's left is to export back to a new csv.

As for the `'\p{Pd}',' '` portion, since `-Replace` is a RegEx operator you can use that Unicode class to cover both em-dashes and hyphens (*just in case that's why it wasnt "working"*).

Comment: \p{Pd} for the dash class, nice

Comment: Thank you for the help, that is great, it works as expected. I will read up more on your soluiotn to better understand it. But it works and does exactley what is needed.